# Callback function opens new window

Tags: javascript, callback, window

I have a situation where a callback function opens a new window. I guess the browser finds the callback is not a user action and blocks the pop-up although everything is triggered by an user click.

I need the callback implementation. Is there any possible trick to use here. Please do not downvote I just need some guidance

```
function checkDoc(function){
 onLoadSuccess{
  function(url) 
}
}

function openDoc(){

function openWindow(url) {
 window.open(url);
}

checkDoc(openWindow);
}
```

Comment: Need more details please.

Comment: will you show us the situation?

Comment: Here you go, please see code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possible trick to use here.

Not really, no. As you've indicated, the issue is that the browser sees you trying to open a popup *not* during the processing of a user event, and quite correctly prevents you from doing that. Options:

1. Your best bet is *not* to open a new window, but to use modern techniques to open a window-within-the-existing-window (e.g., absolutely-positioned divs and such).
2. You can have the callback show a new button (or whatever UI you like) that the user *then* clicks to open the window using the information the callback received. E.g. "Your results are ready, [click here] to view them in a new window." Since you're then opening the window within a user action again, the browser will allow it.
3. A **very** poor third choice to either of the above would be to make whatever you're doing that triggers the callback (ajax, I'm guessing) *synchronous*, so that the `window.open` occurs during the handling of the user event. But of course, synchronous ajax is a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>...

---

Re your edit: So for instance, #2 above would be that `checkDoc` shows something in the UI saying the document is ready, and offers a link to click to open it.

Comment: I have choosen the second option with displaying an progress bar. When the loading is done a button is enabled. The click on this button does my desired stuff.